# Elasticsearch не находит по не полному совпадению

Tags: php, elasticsearch

Добрый день!
Установил эластиксерч версия 5.6
Плагин морфологический https://github.com/imotov/elasticsearch-analysis-morphology
Использую elasticsearch php библиотеку. Вот код

```
$client = \Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder::create()->build();
$params = [];
$params['index'] = ES_INDEX;

//Удаляю индекс
if($client->indices()->exists($params)){
$response = $client->indices()->delete($params);
}

//Создаю запись
if(! $client->indices()->exists($params)){

$params = [];
$params = [
    'index' => ES_INDEX,
    'body' => [
        'settings' => [
            'analysis' => [
                'analyzer' => [
                    'ru_analyzer' => [
                        'type' => 'custom',
                        'tokenizer' => 'standard',
                        'filter' => ['lowercase', 'russian_morphology', 'english_morphology', 'snowball', 'ru_stemming']
                    ]
                ],
                'filter' => [
                    'ru_stemming' => [
                        'type' => 'snowball',
                        'language' => 'Russian'
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ],
        'mappings' => [
            ES_INDEX => [
                'properties' => [
                    'title' => [
                        'type' => 'string',
                        'analyzer' => 'ru_analyzer',
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
];

$result = $client->indices()->create($params);
}
```

Далее индексирую данные

```
$params = [];
$params['index'] = ES_INDEX;
$params['type']  = ES_TYPE;
$params['id'] = 1;
$params['body']['title'] = 'Тестовая метка;
$params['body']['location'] = [
    'lat' => 50.1001,
    'lon' => 25.1002
];
$result = $client->index($params);
```

Данные заносятся в эластик - если искать по ID - запись вернется, но если начать искать по тексту:

```
$params = [];
$params['index'] = ES_INDEX;
if ($client->indices()->exists($params)) {
$params['type'] = ES_TYPE;
$params['size'] = 10000;
$params['body']['sort'] = ['_score' => 'desc'];
$params['body']['query']['match']['title'] = 'тест';
$result = $client->search($params);
}
```

то ничего не находит

> Array ( [took] => 0 [timed_out] => [_shards] => Array ( [total] => 5
>   [successful] => 5 [skipped] => 0 [failed] => 0 )
>
> [hits] => Array
>       (
>           [total] => 0
>           [max_score] => 
>           [hits] => Array
>               (
>               )
>       ) )

Пожалуйста, подскажите, что я делаю не так

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте запрос **simple_query_string** вместо **match**:

```
$params = [];
$params['index'] = ES_INDEX;
if ($client->indices()->exists($params)) {
$params['type'] = ES_TYPE;
$params['size'] = 10000;
$params['body']['sort'] = ['_score' => 'desc'];
$params['body']['query']['simple_query_string'] = [
  'query'  => 'тест',
  'fields' => ['title'],//если не указать поле - будет поиск по всем
];
$result = $client->search($params);
}
```

подробнее об этом типе запроса можно прочитать в документации - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/query-dsl-simple-query-string-query.html]